# How to enable autocomplete for Akka application.conf in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, akka

In IntelliJ IDEA for Akka project not works (earlier works fine):

- autocomplete
- navigation to **reference.conf**

For example I'm have this config:

```
akka {
  http {
    host-connection-pool {
      max-connections = 10000
      max-open-requests = 4096
    }
  }
}
```

My steps for reproducing the issue when not move to reference.conf:

1. open application.conf in project
2. move the cursor on in the middle of **max-connections**
3. press `command + B` (macOS)

I'm expecting for moving to the field **max-connections** in **reference.conf**, but nothing.

I will be happy to know how to fix it.

Comment: Please provide the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: In the example you've linked, what steps would reproduce the issue? From where to where you expect the navigation to work?

Comment: @CrazyCoder, I've added steps for reproducing.

Comment: Do I have to add the code fragment from the issue description to `application.conf` in the linked project to reproduce it? What is the full location of the `reference.conf` file in the linked project where you expect the navigation to work into?

Comment: @CrazyCoder I solve this issue, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How to solve:

1. Install [HOCON plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10481-hocon)
2. Restart IDE
3. Right click on **application.conf** -> mark as HOCON